# How to check Pandas Dataframe for True or False - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ambiguous

How can I check each pandas row in my dataframe to see if the row is True or False?  Here I want to print, 'Yes' if df['check'] is True.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num = [10,20,30,40,30,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
ind = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': num}, index = ind)

df['check'] = (df['Price'] > 30)

if df['check'] == True:
  print('Yes')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you want to know (a) if any row is true, (b) the number of rows that are true, or (c) which exactly rows are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to do this... but use `itertuples`

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.check:
        print('Yes')

Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
```

---

You can map your values with `map`

```
df.check.map({True: 'Yes', False: ''})

0        
1        
2        
3     Yes
4        
5        
6        
7     Yes
8     Yes
9     Yes
10    Yes
11    Yes
12    Yes
Name: check, dtype: object
```

And even `assign` it back to a column

```
df.assign(mapped=df.check.map({True: 'Yes', False: ''}))

    Price  check mapped
0      10  False       
1      20  False       
2      30  False       
3      40   True    Yes
4      30  False       
5      20  False       
6      30  False       
7      40   True    Yes
8      50   True    Yes
9      60   True    Yes
10     70   True    Yes
11     80   True    Yes
12     90   True    Yes
```

---

You can use `pd.DataFrame.where` which keeps the values when the first argument evaluates to `True` and fills in with the second argument when `False`.  If the second argument isn't passed, `np.nan` is placed instead.

```
df.Price.where(df.check, -99)

0    -99
1    -99
2    -99
3     40
4    -99
5    -99
6    -99
7     40
8     50
9     60
10    70
11    80
12    90
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```

---

The sister method is `mask` which does the opposite.  Keeps where the first argument is `False`.  This is an equivalent statement

```
df.Price.mask(~df.check, -99)

0    -99
1    -99
2    -99
3     40
4    -99
5    -99
6    -99
7     40
8     50
9     60
10    70
11    80
12    90
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks i'm just trying to get a better understanding of how Pandas works.  I was playing with the idea of using state logic with pandas.  Instead of print I would set a number == 1.  The problem with np.where(df['check'] > 30, 1, -1) is I want keep my number at 1 until another event happens.  np.where would just set it back to -1 as soon as the statement is false.

Comment: @BillyRay I gave you a couple more examples to play with.

Comment: @BillyRay don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry for not answering so quickly. I posted at 2am and feel asleep. Thanks for all the replies!